# Can a macro remove characters from its arguments?

Tags: c, string, replace, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a macro that will trim off a portion of the string argument passed in?

For example:

```
//can this be defined?  
#define MACRO(o) ???

int main(){
   printf(MACRO(ObjectT)); //prints "Object" not "ObjectT"
}
```

Would it be possible for a macro that trim off the last character 'T'?

Comment: write a `do...while`, calculate `strlen` and print upto `strlen-2`...but it's too broad...

Comment: `#define ObjectT "Object"`, `#define MACRO(o) o`....

Comment: There's no way to do what you want.  You can append characters to identifiers, but you can't remove them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it for specific strings that you know in advance, presented to the macro as symbols rather than as string literals, but not for general symbols and not for string literals at all.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(s) # s
#define EXPAND_TO_STRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define TRUNCATE_ObjectT Object
#define TRUNCATE_MrT Pity da fool
#define TRUNCATE(s) EXPAND_TO_STRING(TRUNCATE_ ## s)

int main(){
   printf(TRUNCATE(ObjectT)); // prints "Object"
   printf(TRUNCATE(MrT));     // prints "Pity da fool"
}
```

That relies on the token-pasting operator, `##`, to construct the name of a macro that expands to the truncated text (or, really, the replacement text), and the stringification operator, `#`, to convert the expanded result to a string literal.  There's a little bit of required macro indirection in there, too, to ensure that all the needed expansions are performed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least it should **print** "Object"...

```
//can this be defined?  
#define MACRO(o) #o "\b \b"

int main(){
    printf(MACRO(ObjectT)); //prints "Object" not "ObjectT"
}
```

And no, you can't strip character using preprocessor only without actual C code (say, malloc+strncpy) to do that.

Answer (score -2):

With the preprocessor? No. It sounds like what you really want to do is something like this:

<sup>Code not tested</sup>

```
#define STRINGIFY(o) #o

char* serialize(char* s)
{
  if (strcmp(s, "ObjectT") == 0) return "Object";
}

int main(){
   printf(serialize(STRINGIFY(#o))); //prints "Object" not "ObjectT"
}
```

Comment: If you are doing it this way, what prevents from your `serialize` just to chop off the character?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure do that if you want, but I'm making an an educated guess to OP's actual problem. Does that really warrant a downvote?

Comment: Not my DV, but this does not answer the question: and please don't excuse yourself in case of a faulty answer: it's hardly a complex code to write and test and demonstrate.

Comment: If you really care, I am not the downvoter. But on the other hand I am making an educated guess that the OP knows how to do it in a runtime.

Comment: @WeatherVane The answer is "you can't do this with the preprocessor" followed by "here's a workaround". I did test the code, but put that warning there because it's silly to take a demonstration for obviously not-real code so pedantically.

Comment: Please do not contradict yourself. The answer posted says *"Code not tested"*.

Comment: I downvoted this before you put in the `strcmp`, you originally had `==`, and this is incomplete because it doesn't even return right. Also you can't